# XPath to get max child element based on attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to write a XPath to get name of the child element that have the greatest year.

Here is my XSLT to get it but the problem is that I somehow need to call a template to format year into number first.

```
<xsl:value-of select="reports/report[not(preceding-sibling::report/@year &gt;= @year) 
and not(following-sibling::report/@year &gt; @year)]/name" />
```

Sample XML:

```
<reports>
   <report year="2012 Q4">
     <name>X</name>
   </report>
   <report year="2011 Q4">
     <name>Y</name>
   </company>
</reports>
```

Expected output: X.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap each compared expression into `substring-before( ... , ' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach, which still contains the code to extract the year number, but avoids the long complication sibling checks

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="reports/report">
         <xsl:sort select="substring-before(@year, ' ')" data-type="number" order="descending" />
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The method is to simply sort the elements in order, but only output the value for the first one.

When used on your sample XML, the output should be **X**

Comment: what if @year needs more formatting? how can I call template inside select? in xstl 1.0

Comment: You can't call a template within a select, you will have to make use of xpath functions, or possibly an extension function. It depends on what formatting you want to do, but you really need to show more appropriate samples if we are going to be able help. Thanks.

Comment: I dont know implementation of formatting function yet but I'd like to know how to call a template/function/whatever from that code

Comment: You can't call a named templated in this case, but you can call either xapth or extension functions. Would it be possible to give a slightly a larger sample XML showing the different types of year you need to format, then maybe it will be possible to determine the best approach. Thank you.